# Routing app with your own voice and offline maps

Tags: gratis, android, gps

I am looking for a routing app based on GPS with those special features:

1. I can use my own voice for directions.
2. It contains offline maps for Germany (and others).

Comment: Omg,! I can't imagine listening to my own voice when I drive, or at any other time!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try **OsmAnd** the link for the App [is here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand)

Comment: It certainly does 2), but so do many others. Does it do 1) ?